# How to sort a dataframe by names in the rows?

Tags: r, sorting, dataframe

I'm working with a dataframe that looks like this:

```
    d <- data.frame(t1=c("name No. 15", "name No. 15", "name No. 15", "name a No. 3", "name a No. 3", "name a No. 3", "name b No. 7", "name b No. 7", "name b No. 7"), t2=c("A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C"), t3=c(1207, 12965, 3453, 9084, 1234, 1239847, 345 , 9837, 879))
    print(d)
```

And I want it to look like this:

```
    o_d <- data.frame(t1=c("name a No. 3", "name a No. 3", "name a No. 3", "name b No. 7", "name b No. 7", "name b No. 7", "name No. 15", "name No. 15", "name No. 15"), t2=c("A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C"), t3=c(9084, 1234, 1239847, 345 , 9837, 879, 1207, 12965, 3453))

    print(o_d)
```

I would like to know if there is a way to sort the df using the numbers in the "names" in the first column to "sort" the way I want to.

Also I already have another dataframe that looks like this:

```
    D<-data.frame(x=c("name a No. 3","name b No. 7","name No. 5"),freq=c(1250165, 11061, 17625))
    print(D)
```

If there isn't a way to use the "names", then I would like to write a function that does the following:

Let k be an int between 1 and 3, and m another int between 1 and 9
then, if `d[m:m+2,1]==D[k,1]` I want to move `d[m:m+2,]` to `d[k:k+2,]` .

The problem is that I don't really know how to begin to do this. Any help would be apreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: I don't understand how are you ordering: should it order according to the numbers in the "t1" field?  Or "a" and "b" in the name field and "t2" field thereafter?  You should look at the constructions like `d[order(d$t1),]` and eventually use `sub` to extract those parts of the field according to which you are ordering.

Comment: It should be order according to the number in the "t1" field. The problem is that the data is about franchises, so they all have almost the same name, except for the number at the end. I'm plotting this data, but my boss want the plot ordered by the names of this franchises. I already tried to add scale_x_discrete(limits=d$t1) but it isn't working. So this is why I want to order the df in first place :/

Comment: There are several names with the same number.  How to handle those?  Arbitrary order?

Comment: Well, arbitrary could work, but if an order is needed, it would be by "t2"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, ensure that you get the numbers out of name data.  You may have to adjust the example if there are more name forms.  The example below removes all non-digits before digits in the `t1`, and transforms these to numbers for ordering:

```
dig <- as.numeric(sub("[^[:digit:]]+", "", d$t1))
d[order(dig),]
```

You may also add more variables (columns) to `order` as Sam suggested.

Comment: OMG thank you very much. You make it look soooo easy :D